# How to simulate mouse events in Jasmine tests in Angular 2 or 4

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am pretty new to Jasmine testing and I am trying to test a directive which handles mouse events like mouse down, up and move. My question is how can I pass mouse coordinates from the spec of Jasmine to my directive and simulate the mouse events. I have searched a lot on this topic but I couldn't find any examples except for [this](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/directives/) one which doesn't do anything like passing the coordinates of the element.

The following is my attempt to write the test using the TestBed configuration in Angular:

```
import { Component, Directive, DebugElement } from "@angular/core";
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { TestDirective } from "./test";
import { MyService } from "./my-service";

@Component({
    template: `<div testDirec style="height:800px; width:500px; background-color:blue;"></div>`
})
class DummyComponent { }

export default function () {
    describe('Directive: Zoom', () => {
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
        let debugEle: DebugElement[];

        beforeAll(() => {
          TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());

        }

        beforeEach(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [TestDirective, DummyComponent],
                providers: [MyService]
            });
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DummyComponent);
            fixture.detectChanges();
            debugEle = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(TestDirective));
        });

        it('mousedown on the div', () => {
            debugEle[0].triggerEventHandler('mousedown', null);
            expect(debugEle[0].nativeElement.style.width).toBe('500px');
        });

        it('mousemove on the div', () => {
            debugEle[0].triggerEventHandler('mousemove', null);
          expect(debugEle[0].nativeElement.style.backgroundColor).toBe('blue');
        });

    });

}
```

My directive is as follows:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener} from "@angular/core";
import { MyService } from "./my-service";
@Directive({
    selector: "[testDirec]"
})
export class Test {
  private initPointX: number;
  private initPointY: number;

  constructor(private ele: ElementRef,
        private serviceInstance: MyService) {
    }

    @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
    onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent) {
        console.log("Entered mouse down");
        this.initPointX = event.PageX;
        this.initPointY = event.PageY;
        if (event.ctrlKey) {
            // do something
        }
    } 

    @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
    onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent) {
        console.log("Entered mouse move");
        if (this.initPointX && this.initPointY) {
            // calculate the new mouse x and y coordinates and compute the difference to move the object.
        }
    } 
 //other functions.

}
```

As you can see inside my test spec, I am passing the null as the event. This will successfully execute and run my tests but instead I would like to simulate the mouse events by passing the mouse coordinates from here. Could anyone give me some resources or point me in a right direction how to achieve this or if it cannot be achieved what alternatives I can look into.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.
Tammy Gonzalez

Comment: you can look at https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/core/ripple/ripple.spec.ts#L75

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you are passing `null` in your `triggerEventHandler`. Instead you should be passing an object. According to your directive, the object should be `pageX` and `pageY` values for both the `mousedown` and the `mousemove` events.

The directive will receive these values and will execute the steps of your logic and then you can expect the value. The `expect's` which you have currently doesn't make any sense as they don't test anything related to the mouse events.

I believe the following type of spec is what you are looking for:

```
it('mousedown on the div', inject([MyService], service) => {
     debugEle[0].triggerEventHandler('mousedown',{pageX:50, pageY: 40});
     debugEle[0].triggerEventHandler('mousemove',{pageX:60, pageY: 50});
     // assuming you are calculating the difference between the second and first objects.
     expect(service.someObj).toBe({x:10, y:10});
 });
```

The above code is crude but I hope it's helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Makes sense. Passing an object worked well actually. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 6):

This should be more readable than the other answers:

```
const btn = btnDbg ? <HTMLButtonElement>btnDbg.nativeElement : new HTMLButtonElement();
btn.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown'));
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing, be sure if you're going to trigger a change in the DOM that you allow it to update. fixture.detectChanges() is your friend in that regard. In the tests, I see you click the element, but immediately check to see the change without allowing a detect changes to propagate up.